# Where to look first for "rhythmic" vibration under load

Tags: dodge, vibration, drive-shaft, engine-load, u-joint

This is in an older Dodge B250 Van, with the Chrysler 318/5.2L v8 engine, not fuel injected.

On a recent long drive, I began to notice the van has what I can only describe as a "rhythmic" vibration issue whenever the accelerator is engaged. This is definitely new.

Basically, regardless of the speed/RPM, or amount of throttle applied, the entire van is shaking for about half a second every 3 or 4 seconds in a very repeatable steady rhythmic way. The vibration isn't coming through the pedals or steering wheel, instead it's the entire body of the vehicle where I notice it most, all the mirrors shake significantly, and the there is a low rumbling/vibration sound seemingly coming from all around.

At first I attributed it to the road surface, since the feeling is somewhat like driving on rumble strips at set intervals.

This vibration goes away immediately when I left off the gas, whether coasting at highway speeds (~100km/h) or lower side-road speeds (50-80km/h). Similarly, the moment I touch the gas, however lightly, the vibration comes back.

Braking appears unaffected, there's no change in the braking performance at all and no vibration when braking.

I am trying to figure out how to narrow down the possible cause of this. It seems like it could be attributed to many things:

- Transmission, Torque Converter, or Flywheel?
- Wheels/Tires/Driveshaft?
- Ignition / spark plug / timing issue?
- Engine Mounts?
- Loose exhaust component?

To be clear, I'm not asking for details on troubleshooting all the stuff in this list. It seems like there's a lot of potential causes for this, so I'm looking for the general high-probability things I should check first based on these symptoms.

Comment: Propshaft / driveshaft uj failing under load.

Comment: I would add suspension to your list.

Comment: @Solar Mike should I expect play in the joint as a symptom in that case, I tried standing on the brakes and shifting reverse to drive and back but don't detect a clunk. Can visual inspection of the U-Joint help me confirm or rule out?

Comment: @GdD I figured if it was suspension I would expect an issue even when coasting, but I'm just guessing at this point, I'll give the suspension a once over.

Comment: Suspensions sit differently when under acceleration, when you let off the pedal weight shifts @CameronRoberts.

Comment: Agree with Solar Mike. Driveshaft UJ could have enough wear for out-of-balance vibration, but not enough to go clunk when shifting reverse to drive, etc.

Comment: I just took a look at them, they are definitely showing their age, but I couldn't get any play on the driveshaft at either end.  It looks they are worth swapping out either way, but I'm still hunting for ways to eliminate other possible causes or isolate u-joints further.

Comment: @SolarMike you were bang on, it was the front U-joint, felt a bit stiff on one axis after pulling the driveshaft, replaced that one, greased the rear and the vibration is gone. I'm going to reword this question a bit, feel free to answer if you want the rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the top comment by SolarMike I investigated the U-Joints first. The problem was ultimately the front U-Joint that sits between the sliding yoke from the transmission and the drive shaft.

I couldn't detect any "clunk" or play in the joints while they were installed in the van, but after pulling the drive shaft the front U-Joint showed clear resistance and jerky motion when moving on one axis.

Replacing the front u-joint, and greasing the rear (which seemed to be in perfect condition) solved the vibration issue.